# BASH getopts define what $OPTARG can be

Tags: bash

```
usage ()
{
echo "USAGE MANUAL"
echo "-u -> displays this usage manual"
echo "-t -> sets EXEC variable to echo"
echo "-t -> sets DEPTH variable to inputed string" 
exit 1
}
while getopts ":t:u:d:" o; do
case "${o}" in
t)
    EXEC=echo
    ;;
d)  
    DEPTH=${OPTARG}
    ;;            
u)
    usage
    ;;
esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

if [ -z "${d}" ] || [ -z "${t}" ]; then
usage
fi
```

If i get it right if i do this:

```
./script -d
```

I have to provide something like:

```
./script -d full
```

The question is, how do i restrict what the argument of d can be. Like if someone types `./script -d full`  or `./script -d empty` its gonna change the value of DEPTH to full or empty, but if they put something like `./script -d infinite` the script doesnt run and echo somthing like wrong argument provided.

Comment: This is wrong: `if [ -z "${d}" ] || [ -z "${t}" ]; then` -- you never set the `d` and `t` variables, you want to use the variable you set in the while getopts loop

Comment: Also, `-t` and `-u` don't take arguments so you want `getopts ":tud:"`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a nested `case`:

```
d) case "$OPTARG" in
       full|empty) DEPTH=$OPTARG ;;
       *) echo 'Invalid depth' >&2 ; exit 1 ;;
   esac
   ;;
```

Comment: so basically i put a case in a case?

Comment: Yes, that's one possibility.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be nested. You can do the validation after you have processed `getopts`.